# How to deal with foreign characters using MySql within Java EE environment

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I want to read data from a csv file and then write to MySql. The data contains foreign Languages.

I got this error when I tried to insert a record, which contains Japanese Characters, into MySql.

```
"1366Incorrect string value: '\xE6\xB0\xB4\xE7\x9D\x80...' for column 'name' at row 1"
```

The SQL sentence looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `MerchandiseMaster` (id,name) VALUES ('20000101','JANIE AND JACK水着　鶯茶系　大胆花柄')
```

My csv file uses UTF-8 Encoding and the charset of MySql database schema is `utf8_gerneral_ci`.

I have put these parameters when I connect to database through JDBC(`mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar`):

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydata?"
    + "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&user=user123&password=user123.");
```

My question is:

Is there anything else that I am missing to deal with foreign characters correctly?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-9 maybe

Answer (score 2):

I found this on a website, so *caveat emptor*, but apparently MySQL's UTF-8 support is incomplete.  In 2010 they added new support, `utf8mb4` that supports the entire UTF-8 encoding scheme.

Add to your MySQL configuration file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here's a [link to the full article.](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)  I haven't tried this out, so test everything carefully first, and *make a back-up of your database before doing anything.*

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information. But it seems that it is not the cause of my problem. I solved the problem by changed character set of all columns that might accept foreign languages to `utf8_gerneral_ci`